# Why does my Perl code overwrite the location of my value in the spreadsheet?

Tags: perl, graph, charts, spreadsheet

I'm trying to create a chart within a spreadsheet (using `Spreadsheet::Write`). 
I only want to put 1 category and 1 value but somehow the value of, well, my 'value' gets overwritten.

I'm adding the series like this:

```
my $chart = $workbook->add_chart( type => 'column', embedded => 1 );

$chart->add_series(
        categories  => '='.$worksheet->get_name().'!$A$'.$aecCells[0],
        values      => '='.$worksheet->get_name().'!$B$'.$aecCells[0],
         name       => $aecParams[0],
     );

print "\n--->".$aecCells[0];

 $chart->set_title (name => 'Plots');
 $worksheet->insert_chart('I2', $chart );
```

Technically, it should take the value from the `Bx` cell but it's not :/, it's taking the one from `Ax` ...which is not really a numeric value but a string so I get a useless graph.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about [Spreadsheet::Write](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::Write)? That has no worksheets and charts. It looks like you actually mean [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel).

Comment: Also it would be useful to see some example data. What is the content of `@aecCells` and `@aecParams`? What is the formula for categories and values supposed to look like in the Excel sheet?

Comment: True, I actually have Spreadsheet::Write and Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Utility qw(xl_range_formula);. aecCells has the numbers of the rows (i.e. 235) while aecParams has the labels to be used (e.g. 'Gain', 'Time', etc.). When I printout $aecCells[0], I do get the "235" value.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add this information in a readable way.

Comment: It looks like `values` and `categories` accept a cell range, you appear to be providing only a single cell.

Comment: And so the behavior will be to go one cell before but not catch that one I refer to? Mmm...weird...Oh well, I'll just provide a column of 0's I guess:/

Answer (score 0):

Putting the name of the worksheet inside quotes and using cell ranges should solve your issue:

```
$chart->add_series(
        categories  => '=\''.$worksheet->get_name().'\'!$A$1:$A$'.$aecCells[0],
        values      => '=\''.$worksheet->get_name().'\'!$B$1:$B$'.$aecCells[0],
         name       => $aecParams[0],
     );
```